# Sonata's Currency Twig Helper returning wrong format

Tags: twig, sonata

I have installed the `INTL Bundle` for `Sonata` which provides a few twig helper functions for currencies.

The twig function is `number_format_currency('currency_code')`

If I have a value such as `2000000`, I would like to be displayed as `£2,000,000`, currently when I run `2000000|number_format_currency('GBP')` it returns `£2,000,000.00` - so with a trailing 2 0s after  the decimal point.

Ive dug in to a little and can see its using symfony's number formatter and it supports a few constants passed in as array, it seems to only support `'FRACTION_DIGITS', 'ROUNDING_MODE', 'GROUPING_USED'`.

Out of these `FRACTION_DIGITS` seems to make sense to change to 0, to this I have tried:

```
2000000|number_format_currency('GBP',{'FRACTION_DIGITS':0})
```

But i'm getting the same number with the 2 decimal points at the end, i'm sure its an easy fix maybe i'm passing the array in wrong or something but its had me stumped for a little while, can anyone help?

Comment: You could try with `MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS`

Comment: No that makes no difference either, i'm assuming: 
```"2000000"|number_format_currency('GBP',{MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS:0})```

Comment: To get around this I've simple used numer_format instead and dropped the currency off the front. Happy to revisit if anyone figures this out.